# correlation between y and two independent variables x1 and x2 in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I have data consisting of some independent variables x1 and x2 and xn and one dependent variables (y). I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can calculate the correlation coefficient between y and (x1x2). I know that correlation coefficient between y and x1 or x2 is calculated by cor(y,x1) or cor(y,x2) using R. But my question is to find the correlation coefficient between y and x1x2. I tried cor(y,x1x2) but the result is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean the two correlation coefficients for the pairs of variables x1 and y and x2 and y? If so, use rbind to create a matrix of the variables and then call *cor* on the matrix.

Comment: No. I mean the correlation between y and both x1 and x2 at the same time. for example imagine in the regression function, there is a term x1x2.

Comment: my question is not unclear. when you don't understand the question it does not mean it is unclear. I thought people here are expert in R but it seems that no one has enough knowledge on that and I just get the very basic answers which everyone knows.

Comment: Actually it is unclear. Do you want the raw correlation between y and the product of x1 and x2? If so, that should be easy to calculate. But perhaps you want the regression coefficient on that product when y is regress on x1, x2, and the product? Please provide clarity so that we can help you.

Comment: Can't believe someone reduced my reputation just because they didn't understand the question. I am looking for the correlation coefficient between y and x1x2 so that we can decide if x1x2 should be in the regression function or not.

Comment: What do you mean x1x2? the product? the division? the sum? something else? This is an unclear question. It is extremely rude to speak of other people like that especially when you are asking for help. If everyone here says that the question is unclear they probably say it for a reason, no? Also, `cor(y, x1x2)` would throw an error not an incorrect result.

Comment: Your description sounds like you're after regression coefficients. Do you have any examples that demonstrates what you're after?

Comment: @LyzandeR It was a mistake putting my question here as it seems people here have very basic knowledge of statistics and R. x1x2 means x1x2. For example if the regression function y=c+ alphaX1 + betaX2 + GamaX1X2, then X1X2 is clear what it is. When there is no operator between to variables then it's definitely a multiplication(*) operator. This is a very basic concept in mathematics. and about cor(y, X1X2), of course it throws an error as it's just a pseudocode to show what I meant. If I knew the correct syntax then there was no need to put my question here.

Comment: It wasn't a mistake putting the question here. You are asking the question to software developers and people here think us such. X1X2 doesn't imply multiplication in a developer's Q&A site and neither does it mean that people dont know that X1X2 means X1*X2. In a developer's Q&A site X1X2 can mean a ton of things. I am a statistician myself and I got confused and some people in here have written books in statistics and are at a level I would love to be after 20years. If you want to receive answers just be clear from the beginning and don't post ironic comments about peoples' level in stats.

Comment: The answer is just `cor(y, X1*X2)` which you could have tried, it is quite intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple regression:

```
lm.data <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
```

or

```
lm.data <- lm(y ~ x1 + X2 -1) # to omit intercept
```

Get a summary of the output:

```
summary(lm.data)
```

Interpret your results

Comment: This does not help me. lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
      1       2       3       4       5 
 -5.364 -14.209   1.918   9.910   7.743 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -44.810     69.247  -0.647   0.5839  
x1            87.640     15.237   5.752   0.0289 *
x2            14.533      2.914   4.988   0.0379 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 14.01 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9787,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9574 
F-statistic: 45.93 on 2 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.02131

Comment: @HimanUCC what is the point of copy/pasting the result of the call to the comment section? Consider adding more information to your original question (not the comment section).